# Работа с файлами c++ через аргументы в терминале Linux

Tags: c++, linux, argv, ifstream

Задача следующая: программа с++ (на linux, через unistd.h) принимает имя файла в качестве аргумента командной строки. Если расширение файла - .txt, то необходимо его вывести на экран, иначе - просто вывести аргумент.
В целом, я примерно понимаю, как можно это сделать, но совершенно ничего не получается... Вот мой примерный код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ifstream>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv){
    if (argc > 0){
        char a;
        int i{0};
        while(argv[i] != NULL){
            a = argv[i];
            if(a.substr(-4,4) == '.txt.){
                char c;
                ifstream F;
                F.open(a, ios::in);
                std::cout << F;
            } else {
                std::cout << a;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Язык учу в институте, уже знаем про указатели, многомерные массивы, функции, директивы препроцессора и т.д., но я пропустил довольно много занятий, потому и возникают сложности... Если кто-то ещё и сможет объяснить, буду благодарен!

Comment: Тут проще переписать с нуля... :(

Comment: тип аргумента в функции `main(..,char*argv` - неправильный. Аргумент `argv[0]` указывает на имя исполняемого файла. Изучайте язык постепенно.

Comment: `while(argv[i] != NULL){` - и всё пошло по известному адресу. Правильно: `while (i < argc) {`

Comment: @LShadow77, элемент массива `argv[argc]` всегда существует и равен нулю. [basic.start.main / 2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2): «The value of `argv[argc]` shall be `0`».

Comment: @wololo хмм... интересно (я нашёл подробнее тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020172/are-char-argv-arguments-in-main-null-terminated). Но всё равно вариант `while (i < argc)` более читабелен.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, разберитесь только, как это работает:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        if (strlen(argv[i]) >= 4 && _stricmp(argv[i]+strlen(argv[i])-4,".txt") == 0)
        {
            ifstream in(argv[i]);
            if (!in.is_open())
                cout << ">>>>> Error reading " << argv[i] << endl;
            else
                for(string s; getline(in,s); cout << s << "\n");
        }
        else
            cout << ">>>>> argv[" << i << " ] = " << argv[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогло, но всё ещё недостаточно... С кодом разобрался, но суть заключается в том, что если введённый аргумент имеет расширение .txt, то мне нужно вывести в терминал содержимое этого файла. Если как вывести файл, я ещё понимаю, то вот с обращением к самому файлу возникают проблемы - не могу правильно прописать путь... Но всё же, вы мне очень помогли, спасибо большое!

Comment: Не понял... У меня же и выводится содержимое файла!

Comment: Зато я понял! Видимо, из-за особенностей компилятора, _stricmp выдавало ошибку что с string.h, что ч cstring, но стоило изменить на strncmp и добавить 4 в конце (функция принимает 3 аргумента, а не 2, как _stricmp), всё сработало идеально! Огромное Вам спасибо! Единственное, что мне не совсем понятно, так это `argv[i]+strlen(argv[i])-4`. Для чего нужно прибавлять к аргументу его же длину, но на 4 меньше?

Comment: Чтобы найти начало предполагаемого `.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь *Harry from Kiev*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        if (strlen(argv[i]) >= 4 && strncmp(argv[i]+strlen(argv[i])-4,".txt", 4) == 0)
        {
            std::ifstream in(argv[i]);
            if (!in.is_open())
                std::cout << "----- Error reading " << argv[i] << std::endl;
            else
                for(std::string s; getline(in,s); std::cout << s << "\n");
            
        }
        else
            std::cout << "----- argv[" << i << "] = " << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: `strncmp(argv[i]+strlen(argv[i])-4,".txt", 4)` — бессмысленно, там ровно 4 символа, так что `strncmp` не нужен, можно `strcmp`. Но так вы не обнаружите файл типа `Text.Txt`